# retrieving Twitter user info doesn't work in flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, security, twitter, cross-domain

I'm building a Twitter search application in Flash and have encountered a security error when retrieving a user's information using the following...

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=

I noticed a crossdomain.xml file returned with the above.

This works

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: A few suggestions:
1. Post the security error you're getting.
2. Elaborate on the process you're using, i.e. how everything's communicating in your app. If you are using PHP (as your tags suggest), describe what you're trying to do with it and how that relates to the problem.
3. Consider adding Flash to your tags, and remove PHP unless its directly relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross domain policy for search.twitter.com permissive:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And for api.twitter.com it's quite restrictive:

```
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
  <allow-access-from domain="twitter.com" />
        <allow-access-from domain="api.twitter.com" />
        <allow-access-from domain="search.twitter.com" />
        <allow-access-from domain="static.twitter.com" />
        <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.twitter.com" headers="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

meaning that the only way to talk to api.twitter.com would be to call a script on your server and then proxy the request to twitter.